# I can't connect to a Flask server from other devices(=not from localhost)

Tags: java, android, rest, networking, flask

My goal is to build a RESTful API communication, between a python server and an android (java) client.

I want to start with a client using the URL in chrome, and then with an android-java client.

I have a very simple Flask server:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/RESTfulExample/json/product/get")
def hello():
    return "Hello !!"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

When this is localhost(ip=127.0.0.1) the communication between the server and the client **works well**.

The problem is when I run the client **from a different device** (I tried with a phone and another computer):

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/RESTfulExample/json/product/get")
def hello():
    return "Hello !!"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    #app.run()
    app.run(host='10.0.0.54', threaded=True)
```

When I run the server and enter this url (http://10.0.0.54:5000//RESTfulExample/json/product/get) in the chrome URL, After 2-3 minutes it returns an ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT error, or an ERR_ADDRESS_UNREACHABLE error.

I don't have a clue about a solution for this simple problem. I will glad if someone here will help me with it.

Thanks in advance !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please set the host in the python script to

```
host='0.0.0.0'
```

With that the Server will listen on all available network Interfaces.

You also have to assign your port (also in python):

```
port=5000
```

And take care, that your **firewall** is not blocking requests.
To change the behavior of your firewall you can use (on windows) the integrated firewall tool. There you can also easily enable **TCP** traffic for port 5000 in your local network.

Sometimes it also happens that you have to enable peer to peer traffic in your local router.

Ps: you also have two slashes in your link

Comment: First of all - thanks a lot !!

The url should stay "http://10.0.0.54:5000//RESTfulExample/json/product/get", or be changed to "http://0.0.0.0:5000//RESTfulExample/json/product/get" ?
how can i see if the firewall blocks requests ?
I emphasize - It works perfectly if i run the client from the same computer of the server. The problem is with a remote connection.

Comment: No, the url needs to contain the ip address of your computer. The host have to be changed in the Python script.

Comment: Windows has an integrated tool to configure the firewall. Just click on start and search for firewall.

Comment: I don't understand what should I do with the firewall.. How to configure the firewall right ? What options should I enable ? I don't want to change important things that will impair the protection of my computer..

Comment: Enable TCP traffic on the Port 5000

Comment: I don't see this option in the list the firewall-windows tool gave me.

Comment: Than add more informations. What windows version do you use? Have you tried to find a guide on google?

Comment: Windows version 6.1.7601. I searched for this option in google but haven't got relevant results yet.

Comment: You are using windows 7. First result on google: http://www.dummies.com/computers/operating-systems/windows-7/how-to-open-a-port-in-the-windows-7-firewall/

Comment: Maybe you also have to enable it in your Antivirus software (if installed)

Answer (score 5):

Try this

- app.run(host='0.0.0.0', debug=True)
- Allow TCP traffic on port 5000
- Turn off firewall

Answer (score 1):

One way to access flask app from another computer is to get the host computer's IP and run it in another computer.

In Windows, go to `cmd` and type `ipconfig` and look for your computer ipv4 address 
E.g,`192.168.0..`  In Linux, use `ifconfig`.

Then, in another machine,

```
http://<host_ipaddress>:<port>/<endpoint>
```

E.g, `http://10.0.0.4:5000/sample`